# Electron-builder: cannot publish to S3 or DO Spaces on Mac, it complains about some proxy issue

Tags: go, proxy, electron, publish, electron-builder

I have a Electron.js application which I am packaging and publishing using electron-builder but when I try to publish it to S3 or DO Spaces it show the error below.

Note: this is only happening on Mac, if I try the same on Windows it works.

```
⨯ RequestError: send request failed
caused by: Post "https://nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/my-bucket/my-app-1.0.13.pkg?uploads=": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp :0: connect: can't assign requested address
github.com/develar/app-builder/pkg/publisher.upload
        /Volumes/data/Documents/app-builder/pkg/publisher/s3.go:169
github.com/develar/app-builder/pkg/publisher.ConfigurePublishToS3Command.func1
        /Volumes/data/Documents/app-builder/pkg/publisher/s3.go:57
github.com/alecthomas/kingpin.(*actionMixin).applyActions
        /Volumes/data/go/pkg/mod/github.com/alecthomas/kingpin@v2.2.6+incompatible/actions.go:28
github.com/alecthomas/kingpin.(*Application).applyActions
        /Volumes/data/go/pkg/mod/github.com/alecthomas/kingpin@v2.2.6+incompatible/app.go:557
github.com/alecthomas/kingpin.(*Application).execute
        /Volumes/data/go/pkg/mod/github.com/alecthomas/kingpin@v2.2.6+incompatible/app.go:390
github.com/alecthomas/kingpin.(*Application).Parse
        /Volumes/data/go/pkg/mod/github.com/alecthomas/kingpin@v2.2.6+incompatible/app.go:222
main.main
        /Volumes/data/Documents/app-builder/main.go:90
runtime.main
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.17/libexec/src/runtime/proc.go:255
runtime.goexit
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.17/libexec/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1581
```

Comment: You will need to show your package.json code in order for people to help you